# How to export and analyze twitter stream results?

Tags: python, twitter

I used the Twitter Premium API to get historical tweets (Python with the searchtweets package).

I exported the stream to a text file but I don't know how to structure and analyse the data.

I want to conduct a basic content analysis. Thanks

```
from searchtweets import ResultStream, gen_rule_payload, load_credentials

premium_search_args = load_credentials("~/.twitter_keys.yaml",
                                       yaml_key="search_tweets_api",
                                       env_overwrite=False)

rule = gen_rule_payload("from:ManonMasse_Qs",
                        from_date="2018-08-23",
                        to_date="2018-10-01",
                        results_per_call=100)

print(rule)

rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
                  max_results=100,
                  max_pages=1,
                  **premium_search_args)

print(rs)

tweets = list(rs.stream())

[print(tweet.all_text) for tweet in tweets[0:10]];

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % place for place in tweets)

f=open("Tweets Manon.txt", "r")

contents =f.read()
```

I tried this code but I get a NameError:

```
> for line in fileinput.FileInput("Tweets Manon.txt"):
>     try:
>         tweet_dict = json.loads(line)
>         tweet = Tweet(tweet_dict)
>     except (json.JSONDecodeError,NotATweetError):
>         pass
>     print(tweet.created_at_string, tweet.all_text)
> 

>      Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#54>", line 7, in <module>
>     print(tweet.created_at_string, tweet.all_text) NameError: name 'tweet' is not defined
```

Comment: put your `print` statement under `try` block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you provide an example? I'm a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, you declare the variable `tweet` inside your `try` block, thus getting the name error when trying to access `tweet` in the `print` statement outside your `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput("Tweets Manon.txt"):
    try:
        tweet_dict = json.loads(line)
        tweet = Tweet(tweet_dict)
        print(tweet.created_at_string, tweet.all_text)
    except (json.JSONDecodeError,NotATweetError):
        pass
```

Comment: It would be great if you could surround your code with some explanatory comment.